# Copy value to other NA cells based upon ID

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to copy values from the `diff` column that has the value to the corresponding empty cells for the matching `client_id`. I am sure this is done easily in data.table, but I'm just unsure how.

So here is my data:

```
client_id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4)
date <- c("1/1/2021","1/2/2021","1/3/2021","5/1/2021","10/1/2021","10/1/2021","11/1/2021","1/2/2021","10/9/2021","15/9/2021","16/10/2021")
date <- as.Date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
score <- c(15,10,19,20,10,25,20,15,10,30,5)
diff <- c(NA, NA, -4, NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, 15, NA, 25)
df <- data.frame(client_id, date, score, diff)
df <-setDT(df)
```

And I'm wanting to end up with this:

```
client_id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4)
date <- c("1/1/2021","1/2/2021","1/3/2021","5/1/2021","10/1/2021","10/1/2021","11/1/2021","1/2/2021","10/9/2021","15/9/2021","16/10/2021")
date <- as.Date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
score <- c(15,10,19,20,10,25,20,15,10,30,5)
diff <- c(-4, -4, -4, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 25, 25)
df <- data.frame(client_id, date, score, diff)
df <-setDT(df)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do this, depending on your data. This is a "next observation carried backward" form of `nafill`:

```r
df[, diff := nafill(diff, type = "nocb"), by = .(client_id)][]
#     client_id       date score  diff
#         <num>     <Date> <num> <num>
#  1:         1 2021-01-01    15    -4
#  2:         1 2021-02-01    10    -4
#  3:         1 2021-03-01    19    -4
#  4:         2 2021-01-05    20    10
#  5:         2 2021-01-10    10    10
#  6:         3 2021-01-10    25    15
#  7:         3 2021-01-11    20    15
#  8:         3 2021-02-01    15    15
#  9:         3 2021-09-10    10    15
# 10:         4 2021-09-15    30    25
# 11:         4 2021-10-16     5    25
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works perfectly. Would you mind explaining how that works?

Comment: There are three complementing strategies for replacing `NA` values: (1) last observation carried forward ("locf"), which fills an `NA` with the closest non-`NA` value *before* it (within a group, as needed); (2) next observation carried backware (nocb), which fills an `NA` with the next non-`NA` value *after* it; and (3) a constant, which replaces all `NA` values with a constant (as it says). *This* one is analogous in `data.table`-speak with `fifelse(is.na(val), shift(val, type="lead"), val)`, but the benefit is that it *cascades*, so it can look more than 1 row ahead/behind.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for explaining that!! Thank you :)